# Encapsulate CSS of custom element with Shadow DOM using lit-html

Tags: javascript, css, shadow-dom, custom-element, lit-html

Trying to make some `css` only apply to a custom element using Shadow DOM. For rendering, I use `lit-html`.

Any ideas?
Or some other approach to accomplish the encapsulation without shadow?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <script type='module' src="script.js"></script>
  <title>LitComponent</title>
</head>
<body>
<lit-component></lit-component>
<p>not styled</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**js**

```
import { html, render } from "./node_modules/lit-html/lit-html.js";

class LitComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    let style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = `
    p {
      font-size: 80px;
    }
    `
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
    render(this.createView(), this);
  }

  createView() {
    return html`
      <p> styled </p>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define("lit-component", LitComponent);
```

### strong text

I expect to have the 'styled' paragraph within my `LitComponent` styled with `font-size: 80px;` and the plain markup paragraph not.

But actually it didn't render my component at all when attaching shadow like this.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend checking out [lit-element](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/), it's a good method of writing web components with `lit-html`.

Comment: @abraham will do, thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved with

```
render(this.createView(), this.shadowRoot);
```